# How to interpret negative voltage in this schematic?

Tags: voltage, schematics, voltage-divider

I got the following schematic from a book. This schematic was shown during a discussion about loads in voltage divider which require negative voltage.

[image: Courtesy: Practical Electronics for Inventors]

Questions:

1. The voltage value -25V at the bottom, what does it refer to? This can't be the electric potential near the negative terminal, because that's supposed to be 0V, right?
2. The 0V ground at the right side, does it refer to the voltage source's negative terminal?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a "curve ball" or trick question designed to upset wrong assumptions that the negative terminal is always 0V. Symmetrical supplies like +12/0/-12 are actually quite common, asymmetric supplies like this are less common but you need to be aware of them and capable of working with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values -25 V and 0 V are absolute potentials, whereas the 100 V is a difference of potentials.

The negative terminal of the not shown power supply is at -25 V. Therefore the positive terminal will be at 75 V because 75-(-25)=100 V.

Comment: How about the ground on the right side? If I'm to build this circuit with a battery as a voltage source, do I need to actually stick something to the ground? Sorry for sounding absurd, I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: If you were to run this circuit you could use two power supplies: one of 25 V connected between -25V (negative terminal) and 0V (ground) and the second of 75 V connected between 0V and 75 V (positive terminal). Alternatively, you could have a power supply of 100 V between negative and positive terminals, and a second one of 25 V between negative terminal and 0 V.

Comment: You can think of voltage in a similar fashion to floors on a building. In Europe we designate "ground floor" to be zero or "G". Floors above are 1, 2, 3, ... and floors below are -1, -2, -3, etc. If you disconnect the building from Earth and float it out into space you are free to call any floor "ground" and reference everything from that. Similarly, on a battery circuit any point may be your "ground" reference but once you make a real earth connection convention is that that's zero volts in your circuit.

Comment: @Andrea, a ground connection is only needed if there is possibility of it carrying electric current, so for this circuit it's not needed, in this circuit it's purpose is as a reference point.

Comment: @Andrea, yes, what Jasen said is true, to run this circuit you would only need a power supply of 100 V in the negative and positive terminals. And by calling -25 V the negative rail, you'll have the rest of potentials and currents shown in the circuit diagram.

Answer (score 2):

All the load voltages are expressed with reference to point 'A' which is also chosen as the 0v, ground node. Implicitly, the upper terminal of each load is more positive than the lower terminal, hence, for example, the lower terminal of load 3 is 25V below its upper terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The best description to use for the 100v power supply is **floating**. It is drawn without any reference to ground. A 100v battery could be one implementation. Bench power supplies may or may not be ground referenced, most can be floated, with care.

There is no need to label the -ve terminal on a circuit as 0v. However, for many circuits like logic, PICs, etc, that's often how it turns out.

The only absolute voltage on that circuit is the ground node on the right, which is by convention, 0v.

When you solve for the potential differences across each resistor due to the current flow from the 100v battery, and then assign the voltage at the node connected to ground to 0v, the other voltages can then be written in.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking at this diagram myself on page 62 of *Practical Electronics for Inventors, 4th Edition*. I mention this mainly to help others find these explanations.

It seems like the answer is simply that voltage is the potential difference between two points and if you measure a positive difference going from a point defined as zero to another point, then that other point is referred to as negative.

You could just regard the negative terminal as being at -25v, which it is by definition, and leave it at that, but that seems to gloss over some aspects of the picture. Zero volts at the "ground" is just a definition, as in, the person who drew the picture decided that this is the point all voltages (which are differences between two points) will have as the second point. As a point of comparison, the 100 volts has an double-sided arrow associated with it that shows the two points it is comparing, which indicates that this voltage is not with regard to the reference point (since the zero volts point was not the second point of the measurement). The two arrows are like a multimeter reading, and if you applied your multimeter to the -25v difference, you would get 25v because the multimeter only knows that the difference is 25v. It does not know that the second point is 25v lower than zero, just that it is 25 volts lower relatively. I say this just to point out that there is a difference between the voltage associated with the double arrow and the voltages that reference the ground point.

Since the authors discussed earlier in the book around page 40 that the earth ground symbol is often used inappropriately for a generic return path, it is safe to assume that they mean an earth ground. I think they just put that in the diagram to emphasize the 0v reference point since earth ground is regarded as a universal neutral point. If you wanted to think of a DC circuit with the earth ground as a generic return, then you could think of there being two batteries in series and the generic return connects in between the two batteries.

One thing I think can also be confusing about the text of this example is that it gives the impression that the third load somehow requires a negative voltage, which I do not think is true. If the negativity is just a definition, how could changing the definition satisfy some fundamental requirement of the load.